# Looking for aux cable that splits surround into standard left/right/ground cables

Tags: audio

I have an old Dell Dimension 8300, and it comes with a 5.1 surround + subwoofer system. The speakers have proprietary connections that connect to the subwoofer, where the subwoofer has 3 audio jack inputs. I can only assume one is left, one is right, and one is ground. I want to know if there is an audio splitter for one aux port (or USB) that sustains the quality of the sound and the surround-ness of the sound.

Comment: 5.1 "Suround-ness" is dependent on **5** speakers FL, FR, CENTER, RL, RR, Plus a Sub woofer (**.1**)  to play sound that was mixed  to have different sounds in that mix sent to the the 5 speakers and sub woofer.  "*I can only assume one is left, one is right, and one is ground*"  Do NOT assume, get the manual or find it online. This will tell you what the connections are and possibly options for stereo sound. You can not really have surround sound out of 2.1  speaker set up.

Comment: If they are RCA ports then each wire/port has a  **+ and -**, (*positive and a minus*). they would not share a ground (-). Some older stereo's did that but it is unlikely that your system does. We do not know who made your system, or model #.   **Get the manual, do some research, join an Audio forum**.  https://www.avsforum.com/forums/

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Sound Design.

The three audio input jacks on the subwoofer are each two channel 3.5 mm TRS (tip-ring-sleeve) connections colour-coded according to the [PC 99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports) standard:

- Lime Green - Front left and right
- Black - Rear left and right
- Orange - centre and subwoofer (both mono)

The subwoofer channel is known as LFE (low frequency effects) in the [Dell documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/dimension-8300/docs). The outer braid in each cable carries the ground return.

These are all analogue audio connections, not USB. If you don't have the original cables 3 x stereo 3.5 mm to 3.5 mm TRS plug cables will be fine. Connect each cable between each one of the input jacks on the subwoofer and the output jack with the same colour surround on the back of the PC.

This will maintain the 5.1 surround sound.

If you want a 2.0 left/right stereo connection (without surround sound) just use a single cable to the lime green jack on your PC and tell your operating system that you are using 2.0 or stereo speakers. You must do this so that the rear left/right and subwoofer signals are sent to your stereo speakers. (In Windows use Control Panel -> Sound to configure your speaker connection.)

You can't have a single left/right stereo connection and maintain the surround sound effect.

I don't understand your mention of an audio splitter for an aux port connection. If I haven't addressed this above perhaps you could clarify your meaning. What is it that you are trying to do?